# how to adjust the ticks of the different y axis in one graph to have the same high

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here I plot a bar graph and a line graph in the same figure:
[image]

There are 2 y-axes, money and increase_rate, each on a different scale.

How can I set the ticks of the two y-axes to be at the same hight?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
time = [2000,2001,2002,2003]
money = [1000,2000,4000,6000]
increase_rate =[2,1,6,12]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

width = 0.75
ax1.set_xlabel("")
ax1.set_ylabel("")
ax1.bar(time, money ,width = width, color = "#9370DB", alpha=0.6)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')


ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)


ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis
ax2.set_ylabel("")  
ax2.plot(time, increase_rate, color = "#FFFF00", lw = 3)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y')
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.grid(color='black', linestyle='dotted', linewidth=0.8, alpha = 0.5)


fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `set_yticks` to set the tick positions.

```py
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, max(money), 5))
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, max(increase_rate), 5))
```